# Unexpected icon shows before CNContactViewController pops

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

I am trying to create a CNContactView forNewContact using Swift. After I click the button, a CNContactViewController should pop up, but some weird logos appears before the view pops. How to fix this?

I am using Swift 4.1, but I have the same issue on my old project Swift 3.3. Xcode version is 9.4.1.

Here is the video demo: [Video demo for Bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWeEdseM4Fk)

Here is the project: [project](https://github.com/xiaodi528/contactviewBug)

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController,CNContactViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func contactViewController(_ vc: CNContactViewController,     didCompleteWith con: CNContact?) {
        vc.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    @IBAction func addContact(_ sender: Any) {
        let con = CNMutableContact()
        con.givenName = "test"
        let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
        unkvc.delegate = self as CNContactViewControllerDelegate
        self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: unkvc),     animated:true)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

2018-06-19 15:52:13.911766-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] Access to     PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or     file a Radar.
2018-06-19 15:52:14.087053-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
2018-06-19 15:52:14.269548-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-06-19 15:52:14.270754-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2018-06-19 15:52:14.342483-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10334a5a0, _UIButtonBarStackView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
2018-06-19 15:52:14.342971-0700 contactbook[5319:1973728] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10334ab00, _UIButtonBarStackView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

---

[image: Unwanted icons]

Comment: @matt still no luck, I add a new link to the project file, could you please take a look?

Comment: @matt weird, I can see this both on simulator or actual device.

Comment: @matt this bug only shows at the first time when you run the app

Comment: @matt that is a screenshot on my iPhone X. I tested on many different iphone simulators and the issues remains.

Comment: OK I finally saw it in 11.4. Try downloading Xcode 10 beta 1, I think you'll find the issue is gone. That's where I was testing before...

Comment: @matt unfortunately, I still see it in Xcode 10 beta 2